# wicd-curses errors on fresh default 14.04 install

Tags: network-manager, wicd, ncurses

I have a brand new fresh 14.04 ubuntu install but cannot get wicd-curses to run. I can use wicd-gtk but I need wicd-curses to work as well.

ERROR

```
~ sudo wicd-curses
[sudo] password for ry: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 1063, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 995, in main
    ui.run_wrapper(run)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urwid/display_common.py", line 757, in run_wrapper
    return fn()
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 1003, in run
    app = appGUI()
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 591, in __init__
    self.update_status()
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 734, in update_status
    self.set_status):
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 161, in check_for_wireless
    ('$C', ip))
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 781, in set_status
    self.update_ui()
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 930, in update_ui
    input_data = ui.get_input_nonblocking()
    AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute get_input_nonblocking'
```

Comment: I am getting the same.  apt-get install wicd-curses and it doesn't work.  But on the up/down icon I get a list of routers.  Will try that next, after I remove wicd-curses

Answer (score -1):

#### Make sure you have curses installed.

1. `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev ncurses-bin`

#### Check out this Issue

1. [wicd-1.7.3 is incompatible with urwid-1.3.0](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wicd/+bug/1429253)

Comment: installed both those packages, problem remains. Any reason the patch in the link you sent has been added to the ubuntu repo version?